# openshift cannot list routes in project

Tags: jenkins, openshift, continuous-delivery

I'm finding my way in OpenShift v3.2 and have been following a blog post that instructs on how to create a continuous-delivery project using jenkins that will build and deploy a demo project. The blog post can be found here: https://blog.openshift.com/pipelines-with-jenkins-2-on-openshift/

What I've done is:

- created a new project in OS called ci
- added a jenkins 2.x pod using the jenkins persistent storage template as described in the blog
- created a demo project with the following command:

  ```
  oc new-app eap64-basic-s2i \
   --param=APPLICATION_NAME=ticket-monster \
   --param=SOURCE_REPOSITORY_URL=https://github.com/jboss-developer/ticket-monster.git \
   --param=SOURCE_REPOSITORY_REF=2.7.0.Final \
   --param=CONTEXT_DIR=demo
  ```

Added the appropriate rights for a service account using the command:

```
    oc policy add-role-to-user edit system:systemaccount:ci:default -n demo
```

next configured a new jenkins pipeline build that makes use of the openshift pipeline plugin. There the only thing I configured was the groovy dsl:

```
    node {
    stage 'Checkout'
       git branch: '2.7.0.Final', url: 'https://github.com/jboss-developer/ticket-monster.git'

       // ** NOTE: This 'M3' maven tool must be configured in the global configuration.           
       def mvnHome = tool 'M3'

       stage 'Build'
       sh "${mvnHome}/bin/mvn -f demo/pom.xml clean install"

       stage 'Deploy' 
       def builder = new com.openshift.jenkins.plugins.pipeline.OpenShiftBuilder("", "ticket-monster", "demo", "", "", "", "", "true", "", "")
       step builder
    }
```

When I start the jenkins job, the checkout and build stages succeed but the deploy stage fails with the message:

```
    Caused by: com.openshift.internal.restclient.http.HttpClientException: {
      "kind": "Status",
      "apiVersion": "v1",
      "metadata": {},
      "status": "Failure",
      "message": "User \"system:serviceaccount:ci:default\" cannot list routes in project \"ci\"",
      "reason": "Forbidden",
      "details": {
        "kind": "routes"
      },
      "code": 403
    }
```

So hope you can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

After throwing everything away and refollowing the blog post steps, I stopped at the point where I had to add the oc policy. I than triggered a new build job in jenkins which resulted in:

```
    {
      "kind": "Status",
      "apiVersion": "v1",
      "metadata": {},
      "status": "Failure",
      "message": "User \"system:serviceaccount:ci:default\" cannot list routes in project \"demo\"",
      "reason": "Forbidden",
      "details": {
        "kind": "routes"
      },
      "code": 403
    }
```

Then I switched to the demo project using:

```
    oc project demo
```

instead of using the command:

```
    oc policy add-role-to-user edit system:systemaccount:ci:default -n demo
```

I used the command:

```
   oc policy add-role-to-user edit system:serviceaccount:ci:default -n demo
```

and for some reason that was the trick. The jenkins build deploys to openshift now and I can continue my journey. Hope this helps someone!